# RcppArmadillo sample.h compiling error

Tags: r, rcpp

I'm writing a package with some functions calling RcppArmadillo::sample from RcppArmadillo.
However I met the following error when compiling.

> In file included from Citrus.cpp:2:
>   ./R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/3.0/RcppArmadillo/include/RcppArmadilloExtensions/sample.h: In function ‘T Rcpp::RcppArmadillo::sample(const T&, int, bool, Rcpp::NumericVector) [with T = arma::subview_col]’:
>   Citrus.cpp:241:   instantiated from here
>   ./R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/3.0/RcppArmadillo/include/RcppArmadilloExtensions/sample.h:45: error: ‘const struct arma::subview_col’ has no member named ‘size’
>   ./R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/3.0/RcppArmadillo/include/RcppArmadilloExtensions/sample.h:48: error: no matching function for call to ‘arma::subview_col::subview_col(const int&)’
>   ./R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/3.0/RcppArmadillo/include/armadillo_bits/subview_bones.hpp:236: note: candidates are: arma::subview_col::subview_col() [with eT = double]
>   ./R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/3.0/RcppArmadillo/include/armadillo_bits/subview_meat.hpp:2608: note:                 arma::subview_col::subview_col(const arma::Mat&, arma::uword, arma::uword, arma::uword) [with eT = double]
>   ./R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/3.0/RcppArmadillo/include/armadillo_bits/subview_meat.hpp:2597: note:                 arma::subview_col::subview_col(const arma::Mat&, arma::uword) [with eT = double]
>   ./R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu library/3.0/RcppArmadillo/include/armadillo_bits/forward_bones.hpp:29: note:                 arma::subview_col::subview_col(const arma::subview_col&)
>   make: *** [Citrus.o] Error 1

The RcppArmadillo I'm using is 0.7.700.0.0.

The same error appeared on both linux and OSX. When compiling using Rstudio, the error message as follows:
`no member named 'size' in 'arma::subview_col<double>'.
no matching constructor for initialization of 'arma::subview_col<double>'`

I used RcppArmadillo::sample in my previous work a lot. It suddenly doesn't work. I appreciate any help.

Comment: This isn't really helpful without context as to what you were trying to accomplish. `RcppArmadilloExtensions/sample.h` has lots of tests so I'm a bit skeptical here.

Comment: Your compiler may be too old. That you are installing via a R 3.0.0 (about three years old / out-of-date) is a bit of a tell.

Answer (score 1):

This feature works on pre-subset data in either `arma::vec` or `NumericVector` Always has and always will. Do not use this with an intermediary vector obtained from a subset operation (e.g. `.col()`, `.cols()`, or `.submat()`).

---

The issue you are running into is you've decided to subset the data within the call to sample. (You've omitted code to diagnose this part, so I'm speculating here.) Since `sample()` needs to work with both Rcpp and Armadillo data types there never was a call to Armadillo specific size member functions. Instead, the library opted to call the `.size()` member function of an `STL` container, which [armadillo supported](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#stl_container_fns), since that was shared between both objects. However, armadillo limits where the member function was implemented to the "active" data structures and not temporaries. As a result, the `.size()` member function was not implemented for `subview_col`.  So, we end up with the error of:

> error: ‘const struct arma::subview_col’ has no member named ‘size’

---

To get around this limitation and *save* memory, use an [advanced `vec` ctor](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#adv_constructors_col) that will reuse memory and, thus, avoiding the need for an intermediary `arma::subview_col` to be created.

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

#include <RcppArmadilloExtensions/sample.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void adv_rnd(int nrow, int ncol, bool replace = true){
    // Create a matrix of given dimensions
    arma::mat X(nrow, ncol);
    X.randn();

    // Show state before randomization
    Rcpp::Rcout << "Before Randomization:" << std::endl << X << std::endl;

    // Randomize each column
    for(int i = 0; i < ncol; ++i){
        arma::vec Y(X.colptr(i), nrow, false, true);
        X.col(i) = Rcpp::RcppArmadillo::sample(Y, nrow, replace);
    }

    // Show state after randomization
    Rcpp::Rcout << "After Randomization:" << std::endl << X << std::endl;

}
```

Sample output:

```
> adv_rnd(3,3)
Before Randomization:
  -0.7197   1.2590  -0.5898
   0.0253   0.1493  -0.0685
  -0.6074   1.3843   0.0400

After Randomization:
  -0.7197   1.2590   0.0400
  -0.6074   1.2590  -0.5898
  -0.6074   0.1493  -0.0685
```

Comment: Thanks very much for help. This is exactly what I need. I did pass a subset of col to the sample function. Now I know how to fix it.